# docker - how to hide build arguments

Tags: docker, environment-variables, access-token

I've recently started to use docker far and wide for my professional projects. I'm still getting to grips with many of the details.

So far, when trying to acquire a software package from a repository on gitlab or github, I have gone the route of acquiring a token, putting the token in some environment variable, and passing that to `docker build` via the `--build-arg` argument and then to the `git clone` command.

However, as I started pushing my images to dockerhub, I was a bit shocked to find that in the "Image Layer Details" section, it displays also the **value** of the environment variables passed to `docker build`, that is, the content of my security tokens. Now, this is not so problematic because I can just revoke them and create new ones everytime I push, but that seems quite cumbersome.

Is there a good way to pass security tokens to `docker build` such that they don't show up in anywhere publicly?

Comment: Are you looking for [Docker Build secrets](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information)?

Comment: Can you clone the repository on the host (maybe even checking the Dockerfile in there), instead of running `git clone` in the Dockerfile?  That avoids this problem, and it would also let you build a non-default branch or even code you haven't checked in yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I want to mention that `COPY`ing the secret (if it's a file) or using `ARG` (with `docker build --arg`) will always be visible (either by inspecting the layers or checking the image with `docker history <image-id>` so those options are out of the question

Docker now supports [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) which enables you to mount secrets during build time.
One way to do this is by adding the following statement in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret <some_command>
```

and during build use:

```
export MYSECRET=bigsecret
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=mysecret,env=MYSECRET -t myimage:latest .
```

The secrets should be available at `/run/secrets/<secret_name>` by default, but you can also specify the destination yourself (check the link).